# How to update the stored date based on another field input value?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Just stored the registration date and expiry date based on no.of.months selected, it's also by database, created by master screen. Now i need if may i change the no.of months in master screen expiry date must the change the date based on the registration date and no.of.months when i change.

Eg: i created the basic plan - 3 months , at the registration i selected the reg. date 2.1.2013 and selected the basic plan, so that i database the expiry date is stored in 2.4.2013.  if i change the month 3 into 4, i need to change the expiry date is 2.5.2013.

Comment: does the expiry date automatically storing in you db?

Comment: yes stored in database automatically based on the inputs of registration date and no.of months selected

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code i hope this will help :

```
$regdate = '2.1.2013';
$expiredate =  date("d.m.Y", strtotime('+3 month', strtotime($regdate)));
echo $expiredate;
```

Then its print **02.04.2013**

Comment: i want to get the regdate date from database , i want to change the deadline date for each and every member individually based on their registration date

Comment: if want to get user regdate then you need a query execute like : "SELECT regdate FROM your_user_table_name WHERE your_condition";

Comment: $reg_date = $this->Administrator->get_date($id);
  foreach($reg_date as $value)
     {
        $date = $value['Reg_Date']; and 
        if($plan_months1 != 0)
        {
        /*$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . ' +'.intval($plan_months1).' month');*/
  $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)).' +'.intval($plan_months1).' month');
        $date = date("Y-m-d",$date);
        }
        $this->Administrator->update_member_plan($plan_months1,$id,$no_profiles,$date);
     }

Comment: i get the registration date for last entered client update the expiry date based on that to all clients which are under the same plan

Comment: @user203889 that means you want to update all member expiry date based on their registration date under the same plan.